# Filtering a list of lists in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, filter

I want a function `Int -> [[String]]`, trying to filter out the elements that have a specific value on the Inth spot. I thought I could combine `filter` and `!!` but I can't get it to work. So far I have:

```
filter (!! (== value)) rows
```

where `value` is a `String` and `rows` is a `[[String]]`. I thought it would take the `Int` combined with a `[String]` from `rows` and check if that particular entry equals `value` and then keep those rows, but it gets interpreted differently. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You say `the Int` – but with Int?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question

Comment: It's often best to start by using explicit lambdas to make sure every function and operator is fully applied, then, if you wish, working to remove them one at a time.

Answer (score 3):

`(!! (== value))` is invalid because the right operand of `!!` must be an `Int`. `(== value)` is a function.

Your options are

```
\n -> filter (\xs -> xs !! n == value) rows
```

or without the explicit lambda

```
\n -> filter ((== value) . (!! n)) rows
```

Comment: This works indeed. Glad to see my idea was correct, but it was my formulation that was lacking.

Comment: @tbpotn  I would recommend reading up on [pointfree style](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree), to avoid future problems such as this.